# How to create nested recycler view in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nestedrecyclerview

[Hello! I want to use same `listview` or `gridview` or nested `recyclerview` but I do not know how to implement this. please help me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsxlY.jpg)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This isn't a nested recycler view. A simple recycler view with 3 imageviews in a row.

Answer (score 0):

create an xml file which is a linear layout and set the orientation property of the linear layout to horizontal.
For eg,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightsum="3">
    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and call this layout in recyclerView adapter class.